Pfc package clusterboot() number of clusters
I am using the clusterboot() function from the fpc R package to access cluster stability.
clusterboot(data_scaled, B=20, clustermethod=kmeansCBI, krange=2:10)

The krange was specified as 2:10
In the results there is the output "Number of clusters found in data:  4"
I am assuming that the function calculates the optimal number of clusters. However, I don`t know by which method (silhouette? Calinski-Harabasz Index?)
Can anyone tell me?
Thanks in advance

To the best of my knowledge, clusterboot does not directly determine the optimal number of clusters (k) using methods like the Silhouette or Calinski-Harabasz Index. See here.
Instead, it focuses on assessing cluster stability through resampling techniques. Specifically, the function uses Clusterwise cluster stability assessment, which evaluates how consistently similar data points remain clustered together across multiple resampling iterations.
